# Pikaday - Trying to figure out why I'm getting an area when trying to set my own values.

Tags: javascript, typescript, pikaday

```
const Pikaday = require('pikaday');

class datePickerModule {
    init() {
        let picker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            yearRange: [1900, 2017],
            maxDate: new Date(),
            i18n: {
                weekdaysShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'] 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Everything with this code works until I add the i18n: property.. I want to change the weekdaysShort to be in this format instead of mon, tues etc.

But for some reason I'm getting the below error when trying to do so.

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

It is worth noting that I am using Typescript to do this and this followed by Webpack.

Any Ideas why this simple code is breaking?

Ta

Comment: The only advice I can give you is to try and use the debugger to figure out what's going on. The code looks good according to the documentation, and if TypeScript doesn't complain, it means that your code is good according to the type definition file.

Comment: Yeah does feel like I'm following everything correclty just wondering if anyone else has had the same problem

Comment: ok but what is undefined ? You can know with your stack trace.